# Info.plist not copied to DerivedData causes compilation error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, info.plist, deriveddata

I have a problem that cropped up quite recently with a project that has otherwise compiled and built just fine for over a year.

The error I receive is this:

```
Showing All Issues
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/julian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OmataRx.app/Info.plist'
```

There are a couple of peculiar things here.

1. First, my *Info.plist* is not named `Info.plist`. It is named `RxInfo.plist` and is indicated as such in the `Build Settings` `Info plist File` section.

[image: Info.plist in Build Settings section]

2. Second, if I go to this directory path, there are no files there whatsoever. Empty directory. So, whatever build phase was attempting to copy the file there, did not do so. But, there is no error or warning of such a step failing.
3. Third, if I copy my named plist file to that directory, change the name to `Info.plist`, everything works fine.

Bonkers, eh?

I've tried a variety of things. I've rebuilt after cleaning, I've deintegrated and then re-installed and re-built the Pods. I've gone to Legacy Build System and attempted that. I had a colleague attempt to build from scratch on their system and they had the precise same error. This all happens on Xcode 11.6. On a whim, I tried building with Xcode 12 beta and had the precise same results.

I'm not sure what to attempt next, to be honest. And dragging-and-dropping and renaming the plist file to that Derived Data directory goes against against everything I believe.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Couple things, is Info.plist set the same for all configurations (click the arrow near the Info.plist declaration as in your image). Could your custom "Preprocess Info.plist File" setting be interfering somehow? Can you just use Info.plist as the filename in your project instead of RxInfo.plist and eliminate all custom settings around RxInfo.plist?

Comment: @Durstann I have tried renaming the Info.plist as you suggested — to just plain vanilla "Info.plist" and there was no change in the outcome. I had changed it to this bespoke name — but then noticed that the build chain didn't seem to care what I specified which aroused my suspicion. I'm also wondering if somehow it is referring to the Info.plist of another part of the build, for example one of the Pods. Still completely mystified..